# How to solve unusual time series plots in Altair

Tags: altair

I've got a simple Altair plot that is supposed to show a quantity over time.

Here's some mock data:

```
year    admissions
2014    200
2015    300
2016    450
2017    500
2018    700
2019    900
```

The code is simple:

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X("year:O"),
    alt.Y("admissions_count_women:Q") 
)
```

But the result, while showing the trend in the peaks, drops to zero between years.

[image]

The problem is that the data is for a year (2014 - 2019) and I've encoded it as int, not as a date

```
year                    983 non-null    int64
```

How do I encode the 'year' data column as a datetime which Pandas knows is a year and so I can see just a straight line?